# How can I ensure a execution after thread saves a result?

Tags: android, string, multithreading, bluetooth, arduino

I'm working on a project Arduino+Android, I'm developing an Android App whose purpose is manage a digital PID motor speed controller, Android App must sent the controller parameters (Kp, Ki, Kd) and the set speed, on the other hand Arduino must sent the current speed and, if I requested, the controller parameter in order to synchronize the values in the Android App.
This sounds great, but I cannot use the last string sent (and save) by Arduino automatically.
The code used for receive data is:

```
public void beginListenForData()
{
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    pauseSerialWorker = false;
    readBufferPosition = 0;
    readBuffer = new byte[1024];
    try { inStream = btSocket.getInputStream(); }catch (IOException e){}
    Thread workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !pauseSerialWorker)
            {
                try
                {
                    int bytesAvailable = inStream.available();
                    if(bytesAvailable > 0)
                    {
                        byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                        inStream.read(packetBytes);
                        for(int i=0;i<bytesAvailable;i++)
                        {
                            byte b = packetBytes[i];
                            if(b == lineDelimiter)
                            {
                                byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[readBufferPosition];
                                System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0, encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.length);
                                final String data = new String(encodedBytes, "US-ASCII");
                                readBufferPosition = 0;
                                handler.post(new Runnable()
                                {
                                    public void run()
                                    {
                                        textView.setText(data);
                                        receive=data;
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                readBuffer[readBufferPosition++] = b;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException ex)
                {
                    pauseSerialWorker = true;

                }
            }
        }
    });
    workerThread.start();
}
```

This thread shows the last string received (since shows it in a textview), and saves it in 'receive' (a public global String), this start basically into app initialization.
I use this code for solicit data and show it also as a Toast.

```
            sendData("#",true);
            sendData("*",true);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), receive, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

When Arduino reads '#' enters into 'write mode' and sent a string only once, after must receive '*' to exit from this mode.
All works, but the Toast is executed before the Thread saves the last string received. How can I ensure the toast's execution after thread saves the last string?
This is vital in order to process the string's information.

Comment: Does the worker thread know when it has received the last string?

Comment: It doesn't, but if I can 'build' a special code. May be something like this into public void run(): if(data=="SpecialCode") ?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: If you're initiating the worker thread from the UI thread and then publishing the results to the UI thread, then an `AsyncTask` is probably the way to go.  [According to the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html):

> **Using AsyncTask**
>
> `AsyncTask` allows you to perform asynchronous work on your user interface. It performs the blocking operations in a worker thread and then publishes the results on the UI thread, without requiring you to handle threads and/or handlers yourself.
>
> To use it, you must subclass `AsyncTask` and implement the `doInBackground()` callback method, which runs in a pool of background threads. To update your UI, you should implement `onPostExecute()`, which delivers the result from `doInBackground()` and runs in the UI thread, so you can safely update your UI. You can then run the task by calling `execute()` from the UI thread.
>
> For example, you can implement the previous example using AsyncTask this way:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    new DownloadImageTask().execute("http://example.com/image.png");
}

private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    /** The system calls this to perform work in a worker thread and
      * delivers it the parameters given to AsyncTask.execute() */
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        return loadImageFromNetwork(urls[0]);
    }

    /** The system calls this to perform work in the UI thread and delivers
      * the result from doInBackground() */
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

> Now the UI is safe and the code is simpler, because it separates the work into the part that should be done on a worker thread and the part that should be done on the UI thread.

Comment: I create a SynchronousQueue<String> queue, when data becomes to "LoL", puts the 'recieve' value on queue.
The problem is when I use the queue.take(); -which is called from onClic function- since it locks the whole application, including workerThread preventing queue.put(data); execution and therefore it meant I'm doing it wrong.
I don't know how to use the global Semaphore. What should I do?

Comment: @JosephMoreno My mistake, I hadn't realized that the UI thread was waiting on the results of the worker thread - the UI thread shouldn't block (which is what would happen with `take()` on a `BlockingQueue` or `acquire()` on a `Semaphore`).  See my edit above - an `AsyncTask` would be more appropriate for your use case.

Comment: I don't understand how implement AsyncTask How can I ensure this execution will be after recieve the last string cause I need use this instruction more than one time sequentially additionally the string information can be a numeric value or a acknowledgment message.